# Div show/hide not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The show or hide not working. the div keeps on showing, even if i select an option which should hide it.
However if i console log, it gives me respective show/hide output. 
The following are sample code:

```js
$('#categoryt').change(function() {
  selection = $(this).val();
  console.log(selection);
  if (selection == "2") {
    console.log("show");
    $('#Subjectd').show();
  } else {
    console.log("hide");
    $('#Subjectd').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
  <div class="form-group" id="formdiv">
    <label for="Category">Category</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="categoryt">
      <option selected>Choose Role</option>
      <option value="1">Student</option>
      <option value="2">Teacher</option>
      <option value="3">Animation Designer</option>
      <option value="4">Content Verifier</option>
      <option value="5">Admin</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="formdiv">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="formdiv" id="Schoold">
    <label for="School">School</label>
    <input type="text" id="School" name="School" placeholder="School" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="formdiv" id="Subjectd">
    <label for="Subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" id="Subject" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="formdiv" id="Classd">
    <label for="Class">Class</label>
    <input type="text" id="Class" name="Class" placeholder="Class" class="form-control" />
  </div>
```

Comment: you have `<div class="form-group" id = "formdiv" id = "Subjectd">` there can only be a single attribute of type ID

Comment: @Rainmx93 thanks it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two id's in your element

```
<div class="form-group" id = "formdiv" id = "Subjectd">
```

change to

```
<div class="form-group" id = "Subjectd">
```

Please remember that your element can only have one ID and that your ID must be unique in the entire page. Meaning you should never have two elements that share the same ID. Class, on the other hand, can be shared by multiple elements and you can have multiple classes on a single element.

i.e

```
<div class="form-group class_two class_three">
```